# How To Implement A Method Signature That Will Return a Concrete Type of an Enum?

Tags: java, generics, types, enums, type-conversion

I want to create a method that will return one of four types from an enum. So if someone wants a filter of `SCAN_RANK_GROUPS`, how can I get the return type of the method to be `Rank`, or if somebody wants `SCAN_MEMBERS` it will return Member. How can I go about doing this?

```
public <T> T scanTemporaryStorage(ScanFilters filter) {
    return (T) filter.performOperation();
}

public enum ScanFilters {

    SCAN_RANK_GROUPS {
                @Override
                public <Rank> Rank performOperation() {
                }
            },
    SCAN_MEMBERS {

                @Override
                public <Member> Member performOperation() {
                }

            };

    public abstract <T> T performOperation();

}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure if this is possible, as (I think) that would mean that you would specify that you're returning an *instance* of a class, rather than a *type*... And I'm not sure that is legal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible the way it's done. My suggestion is to create a superclass `Scannable` for both `Rank` and `Member`, and use that:

```
public Scannable scanTemporaryStorage(ScanFilters filter) {
    return filter.performOperation();
}

public enum ScanFilters {

    SCAN_RANK_GROUPS {
                @Override
                public Scannable performOperation() {
                }
            },
    SCAN_MEMBERS {

                @Override
                public Scannable performOperation() {
                }
            };

    public abstract Scannable performOperation();

}
```

The parent class `Scannable` will have all the shared methods:

```
public abstract class Scannable {

    // have all the methods in Rank and Member
}
```

And have your classes extends it.

```
public class Rank extends Scannable

public class Member extends Scannable
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand about Java, the only way to do this is to specify a return type common to all those types, or, if there is no common type, to return an instance of Object. You can then use instanceof to determine which type was returned

Edit: Well, I shouldn't say that's the only way

```
public static enum ExampleEnum
{
    A{
        @Override
        public Integer returnA ()
        {
            return 42;
        }
    },
    B{
        @Override
        public String returnB ()
        {
            return "Foo";
        }
    }
    ;
    public Integer returnA ()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public String returnB ()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really bad way to do it... Use object orientation to create a shared parent class or interface.

Comment: @AnubianNoob See my first paragraph. I was just trying to be complete

Comment: This is a working implementation, I was just making sure you know that this is not good design... (+1).